# Why does vim say "Not Connected" when I use a remapped key to access a plugin command

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm trying to use F9 to allow NERDTree to toggle. So what I did was the following:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F9> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

When I hit F9, I get the following message back from vim

```
Not Connected
Not Connected

Press ENTER or type a command to continue
```

If I do `:source ~/.vimrc`, my remap for F9 works as expected and NerdTree is then toggled as expected.

Also if I use the command `:NERDTreeToggle` at any point from command mode, it works as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of `:map`? Are there any potential conflicts for `<F9>`?

Comment: Good call both of you. Helped me determine that it was the debugger plugin overwriting <F9>. Thanks for the good debugging tips.

here was the output:

   <F9>          :python debugger_command('step_out')<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/debugger.vim

If one of your want to put up an answer, I'll mark it since I've got less than 100 rep.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that people (and machines) will know that this question has been answered.

Comment: well I guess I can now... but as you saw in my last comment... at the time, I could not. Thanks for bringing this one back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @michaelmichael's and @romainl's suggestion, I was able to determine that I had a pluging overwriting the key .

Answer is... Debug it using :verbose map and then see if you need to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - had `debugger.py` and `debugger.vim` in the `~./vim/plugin` directory. I removed these unused plugins and my mappings returned to normal.

Came to light after upgrading OS X to Mavericks.